# IFS equal to newline character is not working in bash

Tags: bash, ifs

I have a multiline string and I want to split is based on `\n` for which I'm setting `IFS=$'\n'` but it's not working, I've also tried `IFS=` and `IFS="
"` but no luck. 
Below is the sample code

```
IFS=$'\n' read -ra arr <<< "line1\nline2\nline3"
printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
# it only generates array of length 1
```

I'm using `Ubuntu` with bash version being

```
GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later 
<http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Can someone point out the obvious.

Comment: The `printf` would produce the same result if the command succeeded. How exactly are you determining the size of the array?

Comment: You are providing a quoted string, e.g. `'line1\nline2\nline3'`, word-splitting will not occur.

Comment: @tripleee by `echo ${#arr[@]}` results in `1`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin , edited the question still same result, not getting the split.

Comment: The problem is you are not actually reading input, you are providing a string, whether single-quoted or double-quoted, word-splitting will not occur. Your default `IFS` is `" \t\n"` (`space tab newline`), so there is no need to alter `IFS`. This is one of those quirks on how the shell handles a literal. Further, you are only reading once. You seem to be wanting to use `readarray` or `mapfile` rather than `read -a`. You may also be also be confusing `-a` with `-a -d '\n'` where you want to specify the delimiters are `'\n'`.

Comment: Switching to double quotes doesn't change the fact (if anything, the opposite). You apparently want `<<<$'string'`

Comment: Hint: Try `cat <<<"no\nnewlines\nhere"`

Comment: There are some defects in your script including others have commented:
- Even if you surround the string with double quotes, "line1\nline2\nline3" is not interpreted as newline-separated lines.
- `read` is a line oriented command and it exits after a line is read. This means that you cannot use `-a` option when reading a `newline` separated text.

Comment: From what I can tell you actually want `readarray -t arr < <(printf "line1\\nline2\\nline3\\n"); declare -p arr` which results in `declare -a arr='([0]="line1" [1]="line2" [2]="line3")'` (you can use just `'\n'` instead of the POSIX `'\\n'` in the `printf` string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary problem with your attempt is *word-splitting* is not preformed with a *herestring*. From man bash:

> ```
> Here Strings
>    A variant of here documents, the format is:
>
>           <<<word
>
>    ... Pathname expansion and word splitting are not performed.
>    The result is supplied as a single string to the command on its 
>    standard input.
> ```

Bash does provide a *heredoc* (e.g. "Here Document" in man bash) on which *word-splitting* will be preformed with the default `IFS`. However, even then you will still read the literal `'\n'` as part of the contents of the array. Not to fear, bash has provided a specific manner in which this can be avoided with the `-t` option to `readarray` (a/k/a `mapfile`).

A short example as close as I can get to your original attempt would be:

```
readarray -t arr << EOF
line1
line2
line3
EOF
declare -p arr
```

Which results in your lines being saved as desired, e.g. the output would be:

```
declare -a arr='([0]="line1" [1]="line2" [2]="line3")'
```

The other alternative is to use *process substitution* and let `printf` provide the splitting, e.g.

```
readarray -t arr < <(printf "line1\nline2\nline3\n")
```

The key to filling the array without the newlines included is `readarray -t`, the key to allowing word-splitting to occur is to avoid the *herestring*.

Answer (score 1):

from bash manual, bash builtins section:

> read

```
read [-ers] [-a aname] [-d delim] [-i text] [-n nchars]
    [-N nchars] [-p prompt] [-t timeout] [-u fd] [name …]

One line is read from the standard input, or from the file descriptor fd supplied as an argument to the -u option,
```

and the line delimiter can be specified with `-d`

> -d delim

```
The first character of delim is used to terminate the input line, rather than newline.
```

Note that followed by an empty argument `-d ''`, the line delimiter will be the nul character, if there is no nul character in input, it can be used to read the whole input.

However read is slow with even with `-r` mode.

For larger input a faster solution can be to use word splitting:

```
input=$'line1\nline2\nline3'
IFS=$'\n';set -f;arr=($input);set +f;IFS=$' \t\n'
```

note `set -f` to avoid glob matching phase.